# How do I get call parents for libc6 symbols (e.g. _int_malloc) with linux perf?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, profiling, perf

I'm profiling a C++ application using linux perf, and I'm getting a nice control flow graph using [GProf2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot).  However, some symbols from the C library (libc6-2.13.so) take a substantial portion of the total time, and yet have no in-edges.

For example:

- `_int_malloc` takes 8% of the time but has no call parents.
- `__strcmp_sse42` and `__cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info::__do_dyncast` together take about 10% of the time, and have a caller whose name is `0`, which has callers `2d6935c`, `2cc748c`, and `6`, which have no callers.

As a result, I can't find out which routines are responsible for all this mallocing and dynamic casting using just perf.  However, it seems that other symbols (e.g. `malloc` but not `_int_malloc`) do have call parents.

Why doesn't perf show call parents for _int_malloc?  Why can't I find the ultimate callers of __do_dyn_cast? And, is there some way for me to modify my setup so that I can get this information? I'm on x86-64, so I'm wondering if I need a (non-standard) libc6 with frame pointers.

Comment: +1 for MCMC, & welcome to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** As of the 3.7.0 kernel, one can determine call parents of symbols in system libraries using `perf record -gdwarf <command>`.

Using `-gdwarf`, there is no need to compile with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.

**Original answer:**
Yes, one probably would need a libc6 compiled with frame pointers (`-fno-omit-framepointer`) on x86_64, at the moment (May 24, 2012).

However, developers are currently working on allowing the perf tools to use DWARF unwind info.  This means that frame pointers are no longer needed to get backtrace information on x86_64.  Linus, however, does not want a DWARF unwinder in the kernel.  Thus, the perf tools will save registers as the system is running, and perform the DWARF unwinding in the userspace perf tool using the libunwind library.

This technique has been tested to successfully determine callers of (for example) `malloc` and `dynamic_cast`.  However, the patch set is not yet integrated into the Linux kernel, and needs to undergo further revision before it is ready.

Comment: Thanks. On my machine `--call-graph dwarf` was needed instead of  `-gdwarf`

Comment: This happens even with a libc6 compiled with frame pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`_int_malloc` and `__do_dyn_cast` are being called from routines that the profiler can't identify because it doesn't have symbol table information for them.

What's more, it looks like you are showing *self (exclusive) time*.
That is only useful for finding hotspots in routines that a) have much self time, and b) you can fix.

There's a reason profilers subsequent to the original unix `profil` were created. Real software consists of functions that spend nearly all their time calling other functions, and you need to be able to find code that is on the stack much of the time, not that has the program counter much of the time.

So you need to configure `perf` to take stack samples and tell you the percent of time each of *your routines* is on the stack.
It is even better if it reports not just routines, but lines of code, as in [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/).
It is best to take the samples on wall-clock time, so you're not blind to IO.

[There's more to say on all this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I've got both self time and caller time (I used perf record -g to get the call stacks).  I can't do much about the time taken executing dynamic casts (does g++ really compare typeinfo with strcmp??) but I plan to make sure less dynamic casting (and memory allocation) is done.  To do this it would be nice to know what's calling the dynamic cast and malloc functions.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I've got both self time and caller time (I used perf record -g).  Clearly I can't make malloc or dynamic_cast much faster, so I'm trying to find which routines are calling them and fix the worst offenders first.  I think the problem is that the kernel may have trouble unwinding stack frames in some cases (note, not all cases) and I'm curious why the kernel is failing to unwind the stack and find the callers of (say) __strcmp_sse_42.  I **suspect** that this is being used to compare typeinfo objects, but without knowing the callers, its hard to be sure.

Comment: @BenRI: That link discusses how I do it, and *[this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/files/)* has a short slide show of getting an overall speedup ratio of about 700x by finding and fixing a series of problems of that sort.